# jQuery Ajax using webmethod - which object to pass and how to query it?

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, facebook, webmethod

I am quite new to using jQuery Ajax with Webmethods and I've been trying many interations and solutions for my problem, but so far with little sucess, even though I looked at many tutorials and posts.

I have a Facebook login functionality that works well on its own and I am trying to send the unique Facebook user ID to the server. When the page loads it checked if the user is already logged in to Facebook and authorised to use the application. If the user isn't, then the Facebook login button will appear (that bit works fine).

If the user is logged in and authorised I then need to check if he/she exist in the database. If they exist, their profile will be pulled from the database and the parameter the relevant stored procdure needs is the unique Facebook id.

If they are not in the database already, then I want them added to the database and then their profile will show up. Showing the profile on the page is basically done as the last step whether the user has just been added, or he/she was there before.

My Users table contain the following fields:

1. siteUserID (PK identity) - int
2. FacebookUserID (this effectively identifies which user data to
   fetch) - string
3. fullName - string
4. emailAddress - string
5. phoneNumber - string (when the user first added it always equals to NULL)
6. dateOfBirth - date (when the user first added it always equals to NULL)

This is my WebMethod in the code behind file:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string GetUser(string fbID, string uName, string uEmail, string uDOB, string uPhone)
    {
        string constrInner = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        string dbFBUserID = "-1";

        // Check if the user is in the database already
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constrInner))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spInteractiveGameCheckIfUserExists"))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uID", fbID);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                dbFBUserID = (String)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                con.Close();
            }
        }

        // If the user is not in the database yet, add it
        if (dbFBUserID == "-1")
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constrInner))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spInteractiveGameAddNewUser"))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uID", fbID);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uName", uName);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uEmail", String.IsNullOrEmpty(uEmail.Trim()) ? (object)DBNull.Value : uEmail);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uDOB", (object)DBNull.Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uPhomeNum", (object)DBNull.Value);
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        string query = "SELECT FacebookUserID, fullName, emailAddress, phoneNumber, convert(varchar, dateOfBirth, 103) AS dateOfBirth FROM Users WHERE FacebookUserID = '" + fbID + "'";
        SqlCommand cmdShowUser = new SqlCommand(query);
        return GetData(cmdShowUser).GetXml();
    }

 private static DataSet GetData(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                {
                    sda.Fill(ds);
                    return ds;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I am quite confused about the bottom 3 lines of the WebMethod. Only 1 record will always be returned and my UI in the .aspx file is not a traditional one - it's not a table with really tidy `<td> <tr>` tags, but rather, a different structure. In the code above it uses a dataset and .getXML, but I am not sure I even need it - I only need to populate the dateOfBirth and phoneNumber fields from the database.

They are 2 .net TextBox controls. The Facebook script already takes care of displaying the rest: the user's name, email and photo (using Facebook OpenGraph and the unique id).

Here is my relevant .aspx page code (only the bit including the fields I need to bind):

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5">
            <!-- E-mail input-->
            <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
                <label class="control-label">Email Address:</label>
                <div class="inputGroupContainer">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="userEmailAddress" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="Email" Style="width: 85%;"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Born on date input-->
            <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
                <label class="control-label">Date of Birth:</label>
                <div class="inputGroupContainer">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="userDOB" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Style="width: 50%; direction: ltr;" MaxLength="10"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5">
            <!-- Phone number input-->
            <div class="form-group row" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
                <label class="control-label">Phone number:</label>
                <div class="inputGroupContainer">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i></span>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="userPhoneNum" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Style="width: 60%; direction: ltr;" MaxLength="12"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

And lastly, here is the javascript I have inside the  tag of my .aspx page. The jQuery Ajax bit should go where it says 'HERE WILL GO THE jQuery Ajax script'

```
 <script>
        // Load the SDK Asynchronously
        (function (d) {
            var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
            js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/he_IL/all.js";
            ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
        }(document));

        // Init the SDK upon load
        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            FB.init({
                appId: '866636586833975', // Write your own application id
                channelUrl: 'http://www.kufsa.co.il/channel.html', // Path to your Channel File
                scope: 'id,name,email',
                status: true, // check login status
                cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
            });

            // listen for and handle auth.statusChange events
            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function (response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    // user has auth'd your app and is logged into Facebook
                    var uid = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + response.authResponse.userID + "/picture";
                    FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,picture,email', function (me) {
                        if (me.name) {
                            $('#userFullName').text(me.name);
                            document.getElementById('pImage').src = 'http://graph.facebook.com/' + me.id + '/picture?type=large'

                            if (me.email.length > 0) {
                                document.getElementById('ContentArea_userEmailAddress').value = me.email;
                                document.getElementById('ContentArea_userEmailAddress').disabled = true;
                            }
                            else
                                document.getElementById('ContentArea_userEmailAddress').disabled = false;

                            // HERE WILL GO THE jQuery Ajax script - but how do I write it for my purpose?

                            document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'none';
                            document.getElementById('profile').style.display = 'block';
                        }
                    })

                } else {
                    // user has not auth'd your app, or is not logged into Facebook
                    document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'block';
                    document.getElementById('profile').style.display = 'none';
                }
            });

        }
    </script>
```

So my questions are: what object do I pass to the jQuery (dataset? something else?) and how should I query it? If I had a table like structure or a Repeater control with a specified structure I would have been able to do it based on a tutorial like this https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Populate-ASPNet-DataList-by-binding-DataSet-Client-Side-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx.

But my case isn't the same.